# PHP: Check if string contains soft hyphen and replace it

Tags: php, replace

I need to check if a string contains a soft hyphen and if it does to remove it from the string. Any suggestions on the best method to locate it and remove it before saving the string to the database?

Comment: Have you checked the PHP docs?  http://us.php.net/manual/en/book.strings.php

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The soft hyphen is invisible here, but this will remove it:

```
$str = str_replace('­', '', $str);
```

Comment: @anthony No problem :) You may want to comment this line well or use hakre's answer to make the code much more clear.

Answer (score 6):

The soft-hyphen you linked (in case your string is ISO 8859-1):

```
$str = strtr($str, array("\xAD" => ""));
```

Otherwise you need to find the byte-sequence for it in the encoding you use, some values given for [SOFT HYPHEN (U+00AD)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soft_hyphen) for common charsets:

```
 \xAD      ISO-8859-1; ISO-8859-2; ISO-8859-3; ISO-8859-4; ISO-8859-5; 
           ISO-8859-6; ISO-8859-8; ISO-8859-9; ISO-8859-15; Windows 1250; 
           Windows 1251; Windows 1252; Windows 1253; Windows 1254; Windows 
           1255; Windows 1256; Windows 1257; Windows 1258

 \xF0      OEM 775; OEM 850; OEM 852; OEM 855; OEM 857; OEM 858;

 \xC2\xAD  UTF-8
```

Answer (score 6):

None of the answers here worked for me. The only way I was able to remove the soft hyphens is:

```
preg_replace('~\x{00AD}~u', '', $str);
```

Answer (score 4):

**Try this :**

```
$str = str_replace('-','',$str);
```

Comment: That works for regular hyphen but it does not find the soft hypen mentioned here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soft_hyphen.